# A model with "has_and_belongs_to_many" -- how to do a query by a list of id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model Model1 which has in it:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :child_items
```

Is it possible to query `child_items` by their id list? Something like:

```
model1.child_items.where(id: [1, 2, 3])
```

Yes, I can do this:

```
ChildItem.where(id: [1, 2, 3])
```

but via `Model1` it'll be better because I there'll be a join and need not just `child_items` but those that really belong to `Model1`, and possibly among [1, 2, 3] might other ids as well.

Hence, how can I do that?

Comment: Hey, Mongoid or ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use this approach instead:

```
model1_instance.child_items.where(child_items: { id: [1, 2, 3] })
```

Rails allows you to pass table names as hash keys then add any parameters you want to query on.

Comment: Not the association, but *table name*. Also, you've probably missed a call to `child_items`, model instances don't have `where`. [See also.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27106853/rails-pgundefinedtable-error-missing-from-clause-entry-for-table/27107299#27107299)

Comment: I assumed model1 was an instance of the model as it was lowercase, not the model itself. The missing call to child_items is valid though, this didn't return the expected type of model. My bad, I've updated my answer.

Comment: There's still a confusing part about the hash key being (or rather **not**) an association.

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more explicit on the table name rather than the association and also have been more clear that it is being called on an instance instead of the model itself. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Once again, this syntax has absolutely nothing to do with associations, it's just a bare table name, with no inference from the model. PS: downvote not mine.

Comment: OK updated again, hah. And no worries I'm learning stuff too, besides I'm more concerned with a proper answer than a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
model1.child_items.where('child_items.id IN (?)', [1, 2, 3])
```